# Google api analytics : error listManagementAccounts in HelloAnalytics.php

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use this code

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();



 $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
/*$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
printResults($results);*/

function initializeAnalytics()
{
  // Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

  return $analytics;
}

 function getFirstProfileId($analytics) 
 {
    // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

    // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.

    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
.....
```

But I get this error :

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Google\Auth\CredentialsLoader::makeCredentials() must be of the type
>   array, object given, called in
>   /home/julienlakq/new_site/administration/analytics/src/Google/Client.php
>   on line 1052 and defined in
>   /home/julienlakq/new_site/administration/analytics/vendor/google/auth/src/CredentialsLoader.php
>   on line 115

I have followed all the steps : created a jey, created a json key via google

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#3_setup_the_sample

Is anyone had this problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

First : Was using sample for v3 with v4 api :-s

Second : gone form php 5.6 to php 7

And then all is fine ;-)